# In the colliseum I'm ranked 2 in team battles, but I can't fight Wandering Swordsman

Tags: star-ocean-4

Why can't I fight the rank 1? It's just kind of greyed out for me although I'm rank 2 in the colliseum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must fight a number of battles before the Rank 1 contender/team unlocks for fighting. Simply keep fighting the rank 3 over and over, it unlocked after 10 or so battles for me.